# O que é a camada de serviços em DDD?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, services, ddd

Lendo sobre DDD ouvi falar sobre a camada de serviços e estou com um pouco de dúvida em relação a isso porque pelo que li um serviço pode contar lógica de negócio. Basicamente a definição que vi é essa:

> Serviços são classes que contém lógica de negócio, mas que não pertence a nenhuma Entidade ou Objetos de Valores. É importante ressaltar que Serviços não guardam estado, ou seja, toda chamada a um mesmo serviço, dada uma mesma pré-condição, deve retornar sempre o mesmo resultado.

Num outro texto li que existem três tipos de serviços: serviços de aplicação, serviços de infraestrutura e serviços de domínio, sendo que o tipo de serviço que estamos tratando na camada de serviços do DDD são os serviços de domínio.

O que me deixa em dúvida é o fato de tais serviços conterem lógica de negócio. A lógica de negócio não deve ser completamente contida nos tipos do domínio? O que realmente são esses serviços de domínio e como podemos identificar eles?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Em DDD, a lógica de negócio não deve ser completamente contida nos tipos do domínio?

Sim. E, em DDD, Serviços são de fato objetos do domínio.

Em DDD, **Serviços não são uma camada** mas sim um tipo de objeto de negócio.

> O que realmente são esses serviços de domínio e como podemos identificar eles?

O jeito de identificá-los está na sua citação, mas eu escreveria diferente:

> **Em DDD, Serviços são objetos que contém lógica de negócio que não pertence naturalmente a nenhuma Entidade.**

A diferença entre a minha afirmação e a sua citação é que eu tirei a vírgula e o "mas". Não há um "mas/contudo/entretanto/porém" na definição de Serviços. Eles simplesmente são o que são. Também tirei o "lógica de negócio que não pertence a Objetos de Valor" porque Objeto de Valor nunca tem regra de negócio.

## Como escolher onde uma lógica de negócio deve residir

Visualize uma regra de negócio e identifique a qual ntidade ela pertence. A pergunta a se fazer é: ***"qual entidade deve possuir este comportamento?"*** Se você não puder determinar e o design estiver ok, então esta regra de negócio pertence a um Serviço e não a uma Entidade.

Eventualmente uma regra de negócio parece pertencer a uma Entidade, mas afetará diversas entidades daquele tipo e não apenas uma única instância - neste caso a lógica de negócio também pertence a um serviço.

## Comportamentos de Entidades

Veja esta regra de negócio:

- Baixar uma conta a receber que foi paga hoje.

Se você tem uma entidade **ContaReceber**, esta lógica de negócio pertence a esta entidade. Você obtém a intância desta entidade e invoca o seu comportamento **baixaPorQuitacao**:

```
ContaReceber contaReceber = contaReceberRepo.get(contaId);
contaReceber.baixaPorQuitacao(dataReferencia);
contaReceberRepo.persist(contaReceber);
```

## Comportamentos de Serviços

Veja esta outra regra de negócio:

- Expurgar contas a receber incobráveis.

Uma conta a receber não tem como saber que ela é incobrável. Para saber quais contas são incobráveis, você precisa obter os parâmetros de algum lugar. Estes parâmetros serão, por exemplo: contas atrasadas há mais de cinco anos sem interesse de negociação por parte do cliente. São necessários o conhecimento contido em diversas outras entidades para descobrir quais contas a pagar atendem este critério.

Esta regra de negócio naturalmente não pertence a nenhuma Entidade, então ela pertence a um serviço, que seria, por exemplo:

```
ServicoBaixaAutomatica servicoBaixaAutomatica = BaixaAutomaticaService.get();
servicoBaixaAutomatica.expurgarIncobraveis(dataReferencia)
```

## Complementando

Objetos de negócio ou de domínio, em DDD, não constituem camadas; ao contrário, eles residem todos na mesma camada, a camada de negócios (naturalmente), geralmente chamada de **domain**.

As camadas em DDD são:

- **Interfaces:** é a interface do sistema com o mundo exterior. Pode ser por exemplo uma interface gráfica com o usuário ou uma fachada de serviços.
- **Application:** contém a mecânica do aplicativo, direciona aos objetos de negócio as interações do usuário ou de outros sistemas.
- **Domain:** camada onde residem os objetos de negócio (Entities, Value Objects, Aggregations, Services, Factories, Repositories).
- **Infrastructure:** oferece suporte às demais camadas, oferecendo por exemplo mapeamento entre objetos de negócio e banco de dados e serviços de acesso a estes bancos de dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Caffé. Só uma dúvida: a interface de um serviço faz parte do domínio, mas a implementação do serviço pode depender da infraestrutura? Por exemplo, um serviço do domínio pode depender de uma classe da infraestrutura responsável por envio de e-mails ou de comunicação com banco de dados? Vi algo assim num exemplo faz uns dias e fiquei em dúvida. Muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: @Leonardo Isso, a interface do serviço sempre faz parte do domínio e a sua implementação ou parte de sua implementação pode ser provida pela camada de infra. O código na camada de domínio pode explicitamente consumir um classes de infra mas o design mais bacana é quando o código do domínio desconhece completamente a infra e consome só interfaces, e então as implementações da infra são injetadas.

Comment: @Leonardo Assim, o serviço não consumiria o banco de dados mas sim um repositório (que é um objeto de domínio) e a implementação de acesso ao banco seria abstraída pelo Hibernate, por exemplo. E no caso de enviar email, o código do serviço, implementado na camada de domínio, consumiria uma interface também de domínio, ex: `@Inject IEnvioEmail email; email.enviar(..., ...);` e o objeto de infra que de fato envia o email seria injetado pelo framework de injeção de dependências.

Comment: @Caffé, fantástica sua resposta, respondeu assiduamente minha duvida. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Fazer com que a lógica fique fora dos tipos do domínio permite a aplicação de um padrão de projeto conhecido por **MVC** (**M**odel-**V**iew-**C**ontroller) onde o `model` se encarrega dos dados da aplicação, a `view` é a interface gráfica que o usuário interage com, e o(s) `controller(s)` é(são) a parte lógica da aplicação em si.

O fluxo de uma ação do usuário nesse padrão de projeto é desse jeito:

1. Usuário interage com a view. (Informa valores e os envia por um formulário, por exemplo)
2. A view monta um objeto com os valores informados pelo usuário e o envia ao controller. (Um pedido de consulta num BD, para dados de uma pessoa específica)
3. O controller então executa a ordem e colhe os resultados.
4. O controller realiza alterações no model, se necessário, ou colhe os dados dele referente ao resultado da ordem.
5. O controller retorna esses resultados para a view. (Retorna os objetos do model que são equivalentes aos da consulta no BD)
6. A view então mostra os resultados do formulário na tela. (Retorna uma tabela com os dados recuperados pela consulta)

Os serviços de domínio podem ser facilmente identificados como os requisitos funcionais da sua aplicação.