# DDD - Qual a melhor opção (Camada) para consumir um WebService externo?

Tags: c#, web-service, ddd

Pattern DDD.

Eu preciso consumir um *WebService* externo, tratar o retorno desse *WebService* e retornar o resultado através da camada de *Application*.

Seria interessante consumir esse *WebService* na camada de *Infrastructure* e tratá-lo como um repositório externo?

Seria interessante consumir este *WebService* na camada de *Services*?

Comment: DDD é foco no negócio e não na tecnologia. Então se os dados vêm ou não de um webservice não é relevante para determinar onde o webservice será consumido; o que você deve considerar é a relevância dos dados no domínio. Além disso, em DDD não existe "camada services". Em DDD, *service* é um tipo de objeto de domínio e não uma camada. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49607/14584

Comment: No pasta de Repository eu crio um projeto "Services".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Seria interessante consumir esse WebService na camada de Infrastructure e tratá-lo como um repositório externo

Eu utilizaria desta forma, na qual você já dá a resposta na pergunta(obtenção de dados é infra/repo)"