# Agregações e o DDD

Tags: c#, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto aplicando os princípios do `DDD`, eu criei uma classe agregação (`Conta`) ela vai conter as classes (`Agencia`) e (`Agente`) que como (`Conta`) tem tabelas no banco de dados. Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu precisaria criar uma classe `Repository` e uma classe Service por cada uma das minhas entidades (Conta, Agente e Agencia) ou só devo criar o `ContaRepository` e dentro dela fazer as inserções e buscas das 3 classes?

Comment: Não, não precisa criar um Repositório, mas ainda tenho uma resperança de que você não está usando o Entity Framework. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sou expert no assunto mas vou tentar dar uma luz

> Eu precisaria criar uma classe Repository e uma classe Service por
>   cada uma das minhas entidades (Conta, Agente e Agencia) ou solo devo
>   criar o ContaRepository?

**Se entendi bem, a resposta é não pelo seguinte motivo:** 
*"Agregados reúnem uma ou várias entidades em uma única abstração"*
Portanto, um repositório por agregação, ou seja, somente `ContaRepository` .

**Quanto a criação da `service` a definição deixa claro:** 
*"Serviços são classes que contém lógica de negócio, mas que não pertence a nenhuma Entidade ou Objetos de Valores."*

Pela definição acima fica claro quando a utilização da `ContaService` seria necessário.

> Referências:

https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/domain-driven-design-in-practice
https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction
[O que é a camada de serviços em DDD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49607/o-que-%C3%A9-a-camada-de-servi%C3%A7os-em-ddd)